# Nginx returning 404 Not Found

Tags: nginx

I need to route traffic example.com/api to webserver running on port 8080. This is my conf file,

```
server {
            listen 80;
            server_name localhost;


            location /api {
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
                    proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            }
    }
```

I'm getting a response back with the following HTML

```
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
        <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
        <hr><center>nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)</center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try setting 
    server_name localhost;
after port listening.

Comment: Added but did not work

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want `http://your.domain/api/abcdef` to be redirected to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/abcdef
```

rather than

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/abcdef
```

To do that you'll need to modify

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
```

to

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
```

Comment: So in what form you want the proxyed URL be? And please remove `rewrite ^/api(.*) /$1 break;` which doesn't exist several minutes ago. @Pramod

Comment: This is a example URL - http://example.com/api/v1/user/verify to http://localhost:8080/v1/user/verify

Comment: okay. when I access http://example.com I get 200, also I can directly hit http://example.com:8080/v1/user/verify ... But I get 404 when http://example.com/api/v1/user/verify

Comment: I mean accessing http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/user/verify without any domains.

Comment: That won't work, this is nginx configuration on AWS ec2 instance and not the local machine.

Comment: So replace it with `proxy_pass http://example.com:8080/;` and try. Don't forget to reload nginx configuration.

Comment: Do you have access to nginx logs? Both access.log and error.log. That would be helpful.

Comment: Remove this line might help: `proxy_set_header Host $server_name;`

Comment: This is what I see in access.log 71.198.1.192 - - [05/Aug/2018:19:04:13 +0000] "POST /api/v1/user/verify HTTP/1.1" 404 178 "-" "curl/7.54.0" And no error in error log

Comment: Yes, removed proxy_set_header still 404. Now I just have proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080/;

Comment: Please do add a slash after 8080!

Comment: just missed on the comment I have a slash in my config.

Comment: Okay then I have no idea on that. I'll suggest you test it on an local machine first and then migrate it onto a remote instance.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for your help. I will try on my local.

Comment: This worked changing location from /api to location /api/

Comment: Glad to see you solved this. I've never thought of that, cause accessing  http://example.com//v1/user/verify should make no problem. Anyway it's solved finally.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by changing the location.

change location `/api` to location `/api/`